# Elasticsearch - Wildcard search among values in an array field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have in my document a `keyword` field with an array of tags. I want to implement autosuggestions, where user can type part of the tag. Now I wanted to use Wildcard, but I have no idea how to get possible matches (preferably with count).

Let's say I have 3 documents:

1. ["Parrot", "Papaya", "Dog", "Cat"]
2. ["Cat", "Parrot", "Dog"]
3. ["Bobcat", "Catering", "Mouse"]

So for query `"pa"` I want to get:

```
{
  "Parrot": 2,
  "Papaya" 1
}
```

And for query `"cat"` I would get:

```
{
  "Cat": 2,
  "Bobcat": 1,
  "Catering": 1,
}
```

Any way I can do this using my current mapping?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [term aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation) with [include paramater](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_filtering_values_4). Be careful about performance.

```
PUT idx_multi
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding"]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "items": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "normalizer": "my_normalizer"
      }
    }
  }
}

POST idx_multi/_bulk
{"index":{}}
{"items": ["Parrot", "Papaya", "Dog", "Cat"]}
{"index":{}}
{"items": ["Cat", "Parrot", "Dog"]}
{"index":{}}
{"items": ["Bobcat", "Catering", "Mouse"]}


GET idx_multi/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "suggest": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "items",
        "include": ".*ca.*",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "suggest": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "cat",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "bobcat",
          "doc_count": 1
        },
        {
          "key": "catering",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```